# How can I stop libre office sheets jumping when scrolling wide columns?

Tags: libreoffice, spreadsheet, scrolling

Long time sufferer of Windows, moved to Linux Mint around a month ago and I am still getting used to the changes. One very annoying thing that I have Googled, looked at the questions here marked `libre office` and `libre office sheets` and checked the settings but still not found a solution to is this:

[image]

when zoomed out it is manageable but when it is at the default zoom it is frustrating and I am not sure what to do. How can I change the settings so that the scroll bar just scrolls like on Excel and doesn't jump to the next column please? If this is possible anyway, might just be the way `sheets` is designed, I struggled to even think about what search terms to use for this, my apologies if this is a basic question.

Comment: Note: the bounty message should say `I can raise a request on their email list if so`, forgot the `I`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible.

[A ticket already exists that has been open since 2011](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=34689) (with no meaningful progress).

Sources: [[1]](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/smooth-mouse-scrolling-in-calc/49535) [[2]](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/calc-horizontal-smooth-scrolling/12258) [[3]](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/calc-turn-off-horizontal-or-all-cell-snapping-on-scroll/66115) [[4]](https://www.reddit.com/r/libreoffice/comments/lk9pmo/how_can_i_enable_smooth_scrolling_in_calc/)

Comment: Just read through the bug reports, sad to see that is the case. Awarded the bounty early as this answers my question and is authoritative, thank you very much.